# CXF Service Assistance

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cxf

I have a service that was given to me, that basically searches the inventory of a future partner. The file they sent is a compiled .jar file, and a wsdl file. The read me file states that it can be used with XFire or CXF. How do I set this service up using Apache, Tomcat, Spring, or whatever else I need to do? It's a fairly broad question, but I am at a loss as to what to do here.

Comment: ask the person who gave you the jar.

Comment: What is your goal: 1. calling a web service or 2. exposing a web service?

Comment: The goal is to call a web service. I'm trying to receive data from their servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choices are as follows:

1. Hire a Java programmer, or
2. Become a Java programmer yourself.

In your shoes, I'd opt for #1. You probably have enough on your plate running your business to learn the ins and outs of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the jar file you got is actually the generated java beans (jaxb) and stubs (jax ws and the likes). So you should be able to figure our an entry point class there and use that to call the webservice. But as others suggested very little information to really give an answer.  JaxWS docs are here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html